# MongoDB findOne() query regarding array inside of the blog post document

Tags: php, mongodb

So, basically, I am doing some blog work, and, as I am newbie in regards to MongoDB, I cannot construct the right query for this. I just wanted to do a simple, separate page for post edition purposes. So, through the cursor, I managed to use a foreach() loop and list all the comments, I also managed to create the post submission form that works, session manager, et cetera. Here's the deal, I cannot construct the right query for a single post edition. In my PHP file, there's an anchor leading to the edit page, and it uses its comment id for it, likewise:

```
 <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $comment["_id"]; ?>"> edit </a>
```

It directs to the second page by the id of the particular post, a page in which I cannot match the right findOne() query. It always find a NULL value. What I want to do is to find this particular post, and put it into the textarea for user to edit it and then repost it. It is very simple but I have a hard time figuring it out. I read through the MongoDB documentation, but couldn't find anything that satisfies me. The other thing is that MongoDB isn't the most popular, and community is not so vast as with MySQLi.

Here's my post document inside the collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "css-clearfix-explained",
    "title" : "CSS Clearfix Explained",
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53ff7ad2af105b0c0b3c9869"),
            "comment" : " some comment",
            "author" : "maciejsitko",
            "date" : ISODate("2014-08-28T18:54:10.569Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53ff7ae8af105b080b3c986a"),
            "comment" : "some comment 2",
            "author" : "maciejsitko",
            "date" : ISODate("2014-08-28T18:54:32.670Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53ff851baf105b370b3c9869"),
            "comment" : "some comment 3",
            "author" : "maciejsitko",
            "date" : ISODate("2014-08-28T19:38:03.710Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53ff8589af105b3f0b3c986b"),
            "comment" : "some comment 4",
            "author" : "maciejsitko",
            "date" : ISODate("2014-08-28T19:39:53.220Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53ff8599af105b0c0b3c986a"),
            "comment" : "some comment 5",
            "author" : "drummond",
            "date" : ISODate("2014-08-28T19:40:09.149Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5400b5f3af105b750b3c9869"),
            "comment" : "skdjfksfjksdfj",
            "author" : "maciejsitko",
            "date" : ISODate("2014-08-29T17:18:43.671Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

And I really need to find the one post with the proper "_id" (using $_GET['id']) inside that "comments" array. How to solve that?

Comment: I don't think I get your use-case clearly. My understanding is that you know both the `_id` for the _post document_ and the _comment_ contained within the _comments_ array. Now, you want to retrieve only that comment indicated by the _comment-id_ for a given _post document_. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: its about one post specified by the anchor's $_GET variable on another page. I want to retrieve it, and then, by using that, I want to put its content ('comment') inside the texarea to be updated by user (further by update method). So, what I've tried so far, is:

$comment = $collection->findOne(array('comments' => array( '_id' => $_GET['id']));  - This one returned NULL


$comment = $collection->findOne(array($_GET['id'] => array($in => array('comments')); - This one returned NULL as well

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct, I want to retrieve that comment id post by findOne() query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are trying to achieve cannot be done using 'findOne'. Instead you need to use the Mongo DB aggregation.

Essentially, the Mongo DB query looks like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    $match:{
        "_id": [id of the post document]
    },
    $unwind:"$comments",
    $match:{
        "comments._id": [id of the comment within the comments array (i.e. GET param)]
    },
    $project:{
        "comments":1
    }
])
```

What each step in the aggregation pipeline does is:

1. Finds the post document by its *_id* field.
2. Denormalizes the post document by flattening out its comments array. This yields a sub-result in the pipeline which consists of one document per comment in the post document.
3. Find the sub-document corresponding to the comment we seek by its *comment._id* field.
4. Project the *comments* field of this sub-result document which contains the comment you seek.

I am not well-versed with PHP but I have attempted to codify this aggregation in PHP using the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php). Below is the aggregation pipeline, codified in PHP:

```
$ops = array(    
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            "_id" => [id for the post document]
        ),
    ),
    array('$unwind' => '$comments'),
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            "comments._id" => [id for the comment within the comments array (i.e. GET param)]
        ),
    ),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            "comments" => 1
        ),
    ),
);
$results = $c->aggregate($ops);
```

The query should give you the required result, and I hope the PHP snippet works too.

Comment: Ok now, if I want to delete this aggregate query, I tried:

$collection->remove($results);

But It did not quite delete anything.

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete the comment returned by this query from the post document's _comments_ array?

Comment: yes, I'd like to delete the one specified by the get variables. And, I tried this:

$delete = $entries->aggregate($results);
$entries->remove($delete);

Didn't seem to work though. Also, when I tried to echo out the aggregation under the $delete by using var_dump, it returned:

 array(2) { ["result"]=> array(0) { } ["ok"]=> float(1) } 

  . Not sure whether it found something. Looks like it did, but now, how can I delete that I don't have an  idea.

Comment: @MaciejSitko you cannot delete the comment how you are trying to. You cannot use the aggregation result as an object to delete an identical object in the mongo db collection. The deletion query you need is different. 

This question and its answer address the aggregation bit and deletion related discussions would be off context here. 
Please submit another question for the deletion you are trying to achieve and I'll be glad to try and help with that.